# nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread addDepartment controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to register a new department and I getting this error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

I have ensured that this is added to my xml file and the error still persists

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Component classes to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.account.*"/>
```

this is the controller method that throws the exception

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addDepartment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addCategory(@ModelAttribute("command")  Department department,
            BindingResult result) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("department",  departmentService.getDepartments());
        return new ModelAndView("addDepartment");
    }
```

this is the complete stacktrace of the error that I am having when I try to access the controller method

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014) m.chuma.account.dao.DepartmentDaoImpl.getDeparments(DepartmentDaoImpl.java:31)com.chuma.account.service.impl.DepartmentServiceImpl.getDepartments(DepartmentServiceImpl.java:28)
```

this is the department dao annotated with the @transactional annotation

```
@Service("departmentService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService{


    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDao departmentDao;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void addDepartment(Department department) {
        departmentDao.addDepartment(department);
    }
```

Everything seems alright from my debug so far, but the error still persists when I try to access the controller method to return the view. What could be wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: You'll want to check that you have something like `<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>` in a hibernate.cfg.xml or `<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>` in the definition of a `SessionFactoryBean` in your Spring configuration.

Comment: i dont have hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: Surely you have a set of Hibernate properties somewhere, either in a Spring XML configuration file or in a Java class annotated with `@Configuration`?

Comment: I have it in spring xml configuration

Comment: Could you update your question with that XML configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you unsing propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS for your @Transactional definition?
This means that the method will run in a transactional context only if there is already a transaction opened from where you call the methos.

The same thing happens if you use Propagation.REQUIRED?